# Alternative to Spring in smaller applications

Tags: java, spring, java-6

I like to work with [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) features like [`@Component`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), [`@Autowired`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) or [`ApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) even in smaller applications (like batch applications).

I've read that [Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) is now a viable alternative to Spring in enterprise applications. Is that also true for smaller ones? What would be the corresponding alternatives to the features I've mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java EE 6 is not going to be any lighter that's for sure. In the Java EE space look at [jBoss Weld](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Solder). But really good alternate and in lighter weight is google [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

Comment: Dependency injection + Lightweight = Guice! I agree

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Guice seems pretty interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The Java EE 6 Web Profile is suitable for very small applications. TomEE is a good example, it's only some 25MB and runs in 64MB of memory.

Being mostly POJO and annotation based with a good dose of convention over configuration, the programming model is also very light and easy to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

[Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is also a good recommendation for a smaller application. Its main feature is Hot Deployment. And its view technology is like Grails. Its pretty good.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[DataKernel](https://datakernel.io) might be a great option in your case. From the site:

> DataKernel is a full-featured **alternative** web and big data Java framework.
>
> A set of predefined launchers and classes for typical use cases allows you to develop apps extremely fast. Create an **async HTTP server** in less than 15 lines of code with no additional configuration files.

They also have their own Dependency Injection with quite impressive benchmarks:

> DataKernel DI is lightning-fast: **5.5 times faster than Guice** and up to **100s times faster than Spring**.

Note that DataKernel has quite a different approach comparing to Spring framework, it is more like Node.js-inspired